# Triggers Creation on Insert on a View in SQL Server 2019

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.employee_assignment 
(
    employee_id BIGINT,
    department_id BIGINT,
    job_title_id BIGINT,
    manager_id BIGINT,
    effective_start_date SMALLDATETIME,
    effective_end_date SMALLDATETIME,
    action_code VARCHAR(60)
);
```

I populated it with values:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.employee_assignment (employee_id, department_id, job_title_id, manager_id, effective_start_date, effective_end_date, action_code) 
VALUES
     (1,2,8,3,'2018-06-08 00:00:00',NULL,'MANAGER_CHANGE'),
     (2,2,3,6,'2012-08-10 00:00:00','2013-08-10 00:00:00','MANAGER_CHANGE'),
     (3,5,6,3,'2014-07-29 00:00:00',NULL,'MANAGER_CHANGE'),
     (4,1,10,6,'2011-02-03 00:00:00','2015-06-04 00:00:00','HIRE'),
     (4,1,11,6,'2015-06-04 00:00:00',NULL,'GRADE_CHANGE'),
     (2,2,3,8,'2012-08-10 00:00:00','2013-08-10 00:00:00','GRADE_CHANGE'),
     (7,7,1,6,'2021-06-06 00:00:00',NULL,'MANAGER_CHANGE'),
     (1,2,8,8,'2016-06-07 00:00:00','2017-06-07 00:00:00','HIRE'),
     (8,5,7,12,'2018-04-18 00:00:00',NULL,'HIRE'),
     (3,5,6,12,'2013-10-25 22:12:01','2012-08-10 00:00:00','HIRE');
```

Then I created a view of it:

```
CREATE VIEW v_employee_assignment 
AS
    SELECT 
        employee_id, department_id, job_title_id, manager_id, 
        effective_start_date, effective_end_date, action_code
    FROM 
        employee_assignment
```

and two more tables with a copy of `employee_assignment`

```
SELECT * 
INTO employee_assignment_history
FROM employee_assignment;

SELECT * 
INTO employee_assignment_future
FROM employee_assignment;
```

I'm trying to create a trigger that each time a new record is inserted into employee_assignment view, check the following:

- If effective_start_date > current_date, then it should be inserted only into `employee_assignment_future`;
- If effective_start_date <= current_date, then it should insert it both into `employee_assignment` and `employee_assignment_history`

Code:

```
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER t_v_employee_assignment 
ON v_employee_assignment
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
        DECLARE @employee_id BIGINT
        DECLARE @department_id BIGINT
        DECLARE @job_title_id BIGINT
        DECLARE @manager_id BIGINT
        DECLARE @effective_end_date SMALLDATETIME
        DECLARE @action_code VARCHAR(60)
        DECLARE @effective_start_date SMALLDATETIME
    BEGIN
            IF  @effective_start_date >  GETDATE()
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO employee_assignment_future (employee_id,
                                                        department_id,
                                                        job_title_id,
                                                        manager_id,
                                                        effective_start_date,
                                                        effective_end_date ,
                                                        action_code)
                                                        VALUES (@employee_id,
                                                                @department_id,
                                                                @job_title_id,
                                                                @manager_id,
                                                                @effective_start_date,
                                                                @effective_end_date,
                                                                @action_code)
                                                            
    
            END
            ELSE 
            BEGIN
            INSERT INTO employee_assignment_history (employee_id,
                                                     department_id,
                                                     job_title_id,
                                                     manager_id,
                                                     effective_start_date,
                                                     effective_end_date ,
                                                     action_code)
                                                     VALUES (@employee_id,
                                                                @department_id,
                                                                @job_title_id,
                                                                @manager_id,
                                                                @effective_start_date,
                                                                @effective_end_date,
                                                                @action_code)
    
            INSERT INTO employee_assignment (employee_id,
                                                        department_id,
                                                        job_title_id,
                                                        manager_id,
                                                        effective_start_date,
                                                        effective_end_date ,
                                                        action_code)
                                                        VALUES (@employee_id,
                                                                @department_id,
                                                                @job_title_id,
                                                                @manager_id,
                                                                @effective_start_date,
                                                                @effective_end_date,
                                                                @action_code)
            END
    END;
```

However, I receive NULL row added into my tables, when I'm trying to insert a test row:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.v_employee_assignment2 (employee_id, department_id, job_title_id, manager_id, effective_start_date, effective_end_date, action_code) 
VALUES
     (1, 2, 8, 3, '2023-06-08 00:00:00', NULL, 'MANAGER_CHANGE')
```

and it's supposed to be inserted into `employee_assignment_future` since the starting date is bigger than the current date, but it inserts in all the other tables but not into the `employee_assignment_future`.

Comment: Well why did you expect any other result? You never give any of those variables a value

Comment: Considering you are using variables in the inserts in your trigger, you are aware that you can insert multiple rows, and the trigger will fire only once?

Comment: @HoneyBadger I am novice in sql, could you please help me a bit with the syntax? how can I pass the insert values into the variables?

Comment: honestly this is pretty basic stuff if you want to write a trigger. There are many suitable tutorials online. SO is not a tutorial site

Comment: Review the relevant documentation [such as this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Thank you @Stu for the hint, basically I just needed it. I tried tutorials but didn't understand the concept of generic and inserted tables, but then got it. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Posting an answer, since I figured it out, maybe somebody will find it helpful.
So basically had to use inserted table, a special SQL table:

```
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER t_v_employee_assignment on v_employee_assignment2
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
    DECLARE @effective_start_date SMALLDATETIME = (SELECT effective_start_date from inserted)
BEGIN
SET ROWCOUNT 0;

        IF  @effective_start_date >  GETDATE()
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO employee_assignment_future (employee_id,
                                                    department_id,
                                                    job_title_id,
                                                    manager_id,
                                                    effective_start_date,
                                                    effective_end_date ,
                                                    action_code)

                                                    SELECT 
                                                    employee_id,
                                                    department_id,
                                                    job_title_id,
                                                    manager_id,
                                                    effective_start_date,
                                                    effective_end_date ,
                                                    action_code
                                                    from inserted i
                                                        

        END
        ELSE 
        BEGIN
        INSERT INTO employee_assignment_history (employee_id,
                                                 department_id,
                                                 job_title_id,
                                                 manager_id,
                                                 effective_start_date,
                                                 effective_end_date ,
                                                 action_code)
                                                 SELECT
                                                 employee_id,
                                                    department_id,
                                                    job_title_id,
                                                    manager_id,
                                                    effective_start_date,
                                                    effective_end_date ,
                                                    action_code
                                                    from inserted i

        INSERT INTO employee_assignment (employee_id,
                                                    department_id,
                                                    job_title_id,
                                                    manager_id,
                                                    effective_start_date,
                                                    effective_end_date ,
                                                    action_code)
                                                    SELECT
                                                 employee_id,
                                                    department_id,
                                                    job_title_id,
                                                    manager_id,
                                                    effective_start_date,
                                                    effective_end_date ,
                                                    action_code
                                                    from inserted i
        END
END;
```

Comment: Nope - you make a common but significant logic mistake. Your logic assumes a single row is inserted. Fortunately it will throw an error in a situation where multiple rows are inserted - but that is only accidental on your part. And it is not clear why you need to set rowcount (which is a deprecated feature). And the use of a "future" table and a "history" table seems deeply flawed. I will also guess that your date columns should be DATE and not SMALLDATETIME (or any of the related types). It is highly likely you don't use the time portion.